# how to send a string between classes?

Tags: java, android, string, token, call

hello guys I would like to sending string between java class in android studio.
I have class CreateToken.java and MainActivity.java, how can I send **String** `yourToken` to MainActivity.java and how can i receive string `yourToken` in MainActivity.java, and the result of yourToken is **com.example.user.application.CreateToken@`yourToken`** but `yourToken` is not full token , its just 7 charecter.

this is one of my function in CreateToken.java :

```
public class CreateToken {
private ICreateToken listener;

public CreateToken(ICreateToken listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public Call<Token> api(final Context ctx){
    ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String usernameApi = "web";
    String passwordApi = "123";
    Call<Token> getToken = api.postWebService(usernameApi,passwordApi);
    getToken.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
            String error = response.body().getError();
            if (error.equals("false")){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, response.body().getToken(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Smart","Response : Token Show");
                String yourToken =  response.body().getToken();
                listener.onTokenGenerated(yourToken);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Smart","Response : Token NUll");
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Smart","Response : Token Null");

        }
    });
    return getToken;
}
public interface ICreateToken {
    void onTokenGenerated(String token);
}
}
```

and this is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CreateToken.ICreateToken {

    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                   CreateToken token = new CreateToken(MainActivity.this);
                   textView.setText(token.toString());
     }

    @Override
    public void onTokenGenerated(String token) {

    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling CreateToken class from?

Comment: in mymain activity

Comment: check below and follow the steps

Comment: where is the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could use the AsyncTask class from Android framework:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Then use the methods doInBackground to call the webservice and onPostExecute use the response from that call:

```
public ActivityExample extends AsyncTask <clazz1,clazz2,clazz3> {
 doInBackGround(clazz1 clazz){
  return result;
 }


 onPostExecute(clazz2 result){
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, please describe more detail

Comment: @Gusti Your Activity cannot block if you make a HTTP request for example, so for this reason one of the solution that you have is to make your activity class extends AsyncTask, then, Call your method to make that HTTP request in doInBackground and then handle the response of that call in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: but my activity is mainactivity extends appcompatactivity how sould i put your code into my class ?

Answer (score 0):

create an interface ICreateToken within CreateToken class as below

```
public interface ICreateToken {
  void onTokenGenerated(String token);
}
```

Also declare Interface field in CreateToken class

```
private ICreateToken listener;
```

and from your MainActivity pass context in CreateToken class like this

```
CreateToken token = new CreateToken(MainActivity.this);
```

then initialise the listener in CreateToken constructor

```
public CreateToken(ICreateToken listener) {
 this.listener = listner;
 }
```

finally from onResponse you can return token via

```
listener.onTokenGenerated(yourToken)
```

Last and most important

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICreateToken
```

implement ICreateToken in MainActivity which will ask to implement onTokenGenerated in MainActivity there you'll receive your token.

Comment: @Gusti this already is a pretty elaborate answer. Don't be a help vampire and just see how far you can get with what you have been given already

Comment: because i newbie in android studio, I'am still adapt with java rules

Comment: I have try this but the token is com.example.user.myapplication.CreateToken@yourToken. But your Token is not Full token , maybe just some character, where is my false ?

Comment: i set textView.setText(token.toString()) in my MainActivity

Comment: i have edit my question  please correct , where should I to change

Comment: you have to write textView.setText(token) within onTokenGenerated method in MainActivity